# Como actualizar Binarios WIX setup

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

Actualmente tengo un proyecto en asp mvc4, y hay generado un proyecto wix setup;

**Explorador de soluciones:**

- Projec1(mvc)

  - *Properties*
  - *References*
  - *Content*
  - *Controllers*
    -*...*
- Project1.setup*(wix setup)*

  - *References*
  - *Binaries*
  - *Product.wxs*

Resulta que dentro de la carpeta de Binaries del setup tengo desactualizadas las dll y en la carpeta bin del project1 están actualizadas a la última versión. Como actualizo los Binaries de project.setup del proyecto wix?

Answer (score 1):

No estoy seguro que sea buena idea crear un instalador de un proyecto web, pero si la cuestion es actualizar se me ocurre podrias ayudarte con `Build Events`

Desde las propiedades del proyecto podrias crear un comando `copy` que lleve las dlls de un proyecto a la carpeta del otro para actualizar su contenido

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[Using Build Events in Visual Studio to Make Life Easier](http://jeremybytes.blogspot.com.ar/2014/02/using-build-events-in-visual-studio-to.html)